# Prevent the same value from being echoed twice in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have this php script that echoes a new type of dog to a user every ten seconds. Every time the page is reloaded in the that ten-second period, the dog stays the same. If more than ten seconds has elapsed, the dog will have changed.

```
<head>
<title>New Dog Every Ten Seconds!</title>
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root","root","dogshow");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: ", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
?>
</head>
<body>
<?php
echo $currenttime = time();
echo '<br>';
echo $minute_ago = $currenttime - 60;
echo '<br>';
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM dogs WHERE dateused<$minute_ago ORDER BY rand(ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()/10)) LIMIT 1");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo 'uid = ' . $row['uid'] . '<br>';
$uid = $row['uid'];
echo 'dogname = ' . $row['dogname'] . '<br>';
//$result = $mysqli->query("UPDATE dogs SET dateused=$currenttime WHERE uid=$uid");
?>
</body>
</html>
```

It works well, but it has one game-stopping error. Sometimes, the same dog comes up twice! All I need to do is stop the same dog coming up twice.

I've tried lots of things (been all night at it) but nothing works! Really, really would appreciate the help.

Database schematic is as follows:

```
Table Name = dogs
id  |  name  |  dateused
------------------------
1   |  Rover |  1362960167
2   |  Chip  |  1362960123
3   |  Rex   |  1362960178
```

Comment: It's on purpose. I thought I could use the update to record the time a dog has been used, and then use the dateused<$minute_ago to eliminate the same dog being echoed twice. (Providing there's more than sixty dogs, if you follow me!) But, of course, it gets updated every time the code is run. Meaning the dog changes every time, rather than staying the same for ten seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you're trusting your custom, yet creative, seed value for [`RAND()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) to prevent the issue:

```
ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()/10)
```

If the same seed-value is used, the same sequences are produced. I'm just making a guess here, but I think you're going off of the idea that the same-seed value will be generated for a single 10-second-interval so the first value in the sequence will always be the same (during that interval), so the same dog will be displayed each time.

The problem with this idea is that, different sequences can still start with the same value. So, while "random", there's still a chance for two back-to-back 10-second intervals to begin with the same sequence-value and will consequently result in displaying the same dog.

**UPDATE** (potential solution /  guess)
Using the code that's currently in your question, you can take your `UPDATE` clause and change the timestamp that's being saved "slightly". Instead of saving the `$currenttime` value, just save `ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() / 10)` - the value you're using for your seed value. So, the update line will look like:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE dogs SET dateused=ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() / 10) WHERE uid=$uid");
```

If you do this, you can use `$minute_ago = round((time() - 60) / 10);` and use it as-is in your `SELECT` query to get things working.

The reasoning behind this is that `ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() / 10)` will produce the same value for every 10-second-interval, as will `round((time() - 60) / 10)`. So, for any 10-second-interval, each equation will produce a non-changing value.

Comment: Yes, you're right :L Any inklings of some kind of workaround?

Comment: @JWH Trying to think of one... it's a toughy for me =P

Comment: @JWH I've made an update with a guess for you. Give it a shot and let me know if it works out or not =]

Comment: Ah fraid not. Implemented, and understand your reasoning, but it didn't work. Oh well, to use a pun, I think I'm barking up the wrong tree anyway, should probably be using a cron job :) Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

use `DISTINCT` in your query

```
SELECT DISTINCT name, * FROM dogs WHERE dateused<$minute_ago ORDER BY rand(ROUND(UNIX_TIMESTAMP()/10)) LIMIT 1
```

Comment: `DISTINCT` returns a "single row" for each duplicate record; The OP only needs a single record (hence the `LIMIT 1` in their query) so this part is taken care of. The problem the OP is experiencing, if I understand correctly, is that the same "dog" is appearing back-to-back (i.e. in two separate 10-second intervals).

Comment: @newfurniturey Yes, you understand completely!